# How can I troubleshoot Delayed Job procs that are failing silently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I will start Delayed Job with the following command:

script/delayed_job -n 4 start

Then at the end of the day I will check to see how many processes I have left, and there might be two. Or zero.

I can't figure out what is causing the procs to die. The logs are huge, I don't see how I can use them to figure it out. Is there something I can do to troubleshoot Delayed Job in this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some starting points to consider:

- wrap your calls into a rescue block and send yourself an email when something crashes.
- create an [at exit handler](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/166093) to see if the program exits normally.
- use some kind of processing monitor to see when your processes end. Something like [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/) perhaps, even though I'm not familiar with it.

Hope this is a good start, good luck with figuring it out.